# summation of sub-matrices of boolean numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, matrix

I have a `11x51` boolean matrix `a`. On this I do this operation in Matlab to obtain a boolean matrix of size `10x50`.

```
a = logical(a(1:end-1,1:end-1) + a(2:end,1:end-1) + a(1:end-1,2:end) + a(2:end,2:end))
```

I want to do this in python. I tried this:-

```
a = np.zeros([11,51], dtype=bool)
a=a[0:-2,0:-2] + a[1:-1,0:-2] + a[0:-2,1:-1] + a[1:-1,1:-1]
```

I ended up with `9x49` matrix and I am not sure if it's doing the expected operation.

Can someone point out the mistake?

Comment: `[:-2]` will remove two elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`slicing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing), it would be -

```
a_out = (a[:-1,:-1] + a[1:,:-1] + a[:-1,1:] + a[1:,1:]).astype(bool)
```

Since, `a` is already a boolean array, we can skip the `bool` conversion.

Sample run on MATLAB -

```
>> a = logical([
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]);
>> a(1:end-1,1:end-1) + a(2:end,1:end-1) + a(1:end-1,2:end) + a(2:end,2:end)
ans =
     3     2     1     2     1
     3     2     1     2     2
     2     1     1     3     3
     0     1     1     2     3
     0     1     2     3     3
>> logical(a(1:end-1,1:end-1) + a(2:end,1:end-1) + ...
           a(1:end-1,2:end)   + a(2:end,2:end))
ans =
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     1
```

Sample run on NumPy -

```
In [160]: a  # Same data as in MATLAB sample
Out[160]: 
array([[ True,  True, False,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

In [161]: (a[:-1,:-1] + a[1:,:-1] + a[:-1,1:] + a[1:,1:])
Out[161]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

Slicing in python are a bit different than Matlab.  Try these in Python:

**All but last element:**

```
[:-1]
```

**All but first element:**

```
[1:]
```